# Most efficient way to compute products of polynomials of same degree n

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, change-of-basis

Say we consider a finite field $GF(p)=F_p$ and define some polynomials $f,g\in F_p[x]$. Let 
$$f(B) := \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_iB^i,\\ 
g(B)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} b_iB^i $$
where $B$ might be a basis of any field extension or a power of 2. (In my specific case I consider $B=2^{32}$)

The aim is to compute "$f*g$" with carring "$a_ib_i > B$?" to the next state.

- If I do the schoolbook method I will get $n^2$ products and $(n-1)^2$ sums. There will be some further sums in the "carry-case".
- The Karatsuba method will have less multiplication but more additions.
- The recursive Karatsuba could have less multiplication, than Kratsuba.
- Montgomery multiplication is actually unknown to me.
- Number-Theoretic Transform is also unknown to me.

## Aims of this question

- Determine the most powerful multiplication method for polynomials over finite fields
- Consider a reduction polynomial and determine the most powerful multiplication in that case.
- Learn how use this method

I know, that none of those algorithms is the best at all, but in a specific range, depending on $n$ and $p$. Say $16\geq  n \geq 11$ and $p\sim2^{340}$ prime. Furthermore we could consider $p\equiv -3 \bmod 8$, if this has any effect.

So I would recommend to first determine, how many multiplications and additions have to be done, for computing the product and consider then a method.

I'm interested in learning those methods for applying in the cases n=11 and n=16 with reduction polynomial $x^{16}-2$. But we only have to consider the first case.

## Edit: Schoolbook Multiplication

If I programm the multiplication, the result is allways false. It can easily be checked by sage.

So I will present you my inner logic on a small example, and if there is some more space, with a M(n)WE. [Minimal (not) Working Example :) ]

So suggest we have a number A to the base $g=2^{32}$ represented as $A=\sum^n_{k=0} a_kg^k$. Then a Product of two such numbers will lead to

$$A\cdot B = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-2} g^k \sum\limits_{h=0}^k (a_h \cdot b_{k-h})$$

## working example

This is my starting point. Suppose we have n=3 and do the equal ordering of coefficients. Storing it as an array in type "arr"

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define SOA 3
typedef uint32_t arr[SOA];
```

now we start to deal with the multiplication

```
void arr_multiplication(arr A, arr B, arr C)
{  
    /* C = A*B
        require two arrays of size of arr, to keep store the result in
        + arr array, carry_array
            + array stores the least 3 entries of 32-bit
            + carry_array stoes the first 3 entries. 
            => C    = carry_array[2] . ... . carry_array[0] . array[2] . ... . array[0]
                    = (c_5,...,c_0)
        require different sized, to deal with overflow:
        + uint64_t c, carry
        + uint32_t carry1, carry2, left, right
            + carry1 stores the overflow of 32-bit
            + carry2 stores the overflow of 64-bit
            + left and right are split-holder
        require counter
        + short i, h, j;
    */
    arr array = {0x0}, carry_array = {0x0};
    uint64_t c, carry;
    uint32_t carry1=0, carry2=0, left, right;
    short i,h,j;

    // fill "array"
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        h=0; 
        carry = 0;
        for(j=i; j>=0; j--)
        {
            c = (uint64_t) A[h] * B[j];     // cast for dealing with overflow.
            split32(c, &left, &right);      // handle overflow

            c = (uint64_t) right + carry1 + array[i];   // add carry and last round-storage
            carry1 = 0;                                 // reset carry1

            carry += (uint64_t) left;                   

            split32(c, &left, &right);

            carry += left;
            array[i] = right; 
            // increase and decrease the counters
            h+=1;
        }
        C[i]=array[i];
        carry += carry2;
        split32(carry, &carry2, &carry1);
    }
}
```

This should fill the lower cases, but it does not. A test will reveal that this goes wrong. Consider the given example-arrays.

```
void main()
{
    arr A = {0xd45a950a, 0xc81aad59, 0x6cf1d82e},
        B = {0xa1170e7d, 0x74fe38a9, 0x5e688b75},
        C = {0x0},
        array_sol = {0x524751e2, 0xa4732df2, 0x5b3a3eef},
        carry_sol = {0x215f0468, 0x4d2e108c, 0x282d4afa};

    arr_multiplication(A, B, C);
    print_hex(C); 
    print_hex(array_sol); 
}
```

split32 could be done by:

```
void split32(uint64_t element, uint32_t* left, uint32_t* right){
    *left = (element >> 32);
    *right = (uint32_t) element;
}
```

Do you see, where I did an mistake? I cant figure it out.

### Fixed

## Some useful sources

[NTT] http://www.apfloat.org/ntt.html

Comment: Sorry. I cannot make head or tails of this.If you are multiplying polynomials then there will never be any carry. It's not like, for example, cubic terms of a polynomial could suddenly add up to a degree four term. Are you just doing multiplication modulo $p$? Then you may benefit from handling groups of bits at once (for example Karatsuba style), but then I don't understand why you bring up the irreducible polynomial $x^{16}-2$.

Comment: That polynomial only takes effect on n=16. Where f and g are then representations of GF(p^16) elements with coefficients over GF(p). The other case (n=11) appears, if we consider an element of GF(p) and split it up in sums to the Base $2^{32}$. The product will then be of degree 20, instead of 11. The last step is to reduce this representation mod p, where p is also a sum to the base $2^{32}$. The mentioned carry appears, if a product of two coefficients is bigger then its base-faktor $B^k$. This will then be carried to $B^{k+1}$.

Comment: If there is a method to compute the product of two elements represented to the base $2^{32}$ mod some big prime, I would be happy to hear about it :)

Comment: Ok. So you are still implementing the field $GF(p^{16})=GF(p)(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a zero of the irreducible polynomial $x^{16}-2$. The elements of $GF(p^{16})$ are then sums of the form $\sum_{j=0}^{15}a_j\alpha^j$, where the coefficients $a_j$ come from $GF(p)$. So any sum or product only involving $a_j$s is done modulo $p$, and the products of powers of $\alpha$ follow the rule $\alpha^i\cdot\alpha^j=\alpha^{i+j}$, if $i+j<16$, and $\alpha^i\cdot\alpha^j=2\alpha^{i+j-16}$, if $i+j\ge16$.

Comment: You can certainly apply ideas from Karatsuba's algorithm, when you calculate a product like
$$(\sum_ja_j\alpha^j)(\sum_jb_j\alpha^j).$$ Just treat them as polynomials in $\alpha$. Internally, as $p$ is quite large, you also want to  apply another Karatsuba to calculate products $a_ib_j$ modulo $p$. And there (but only there), you can write the coefficients $a_j$ in base $2^{32}$. But the elements of $GF(p^{16})$ cannot be written in base $2^{32}$ in any sensible way - at least I'm not aware of one. Surely, internally elements of $GF(p^{16})$ are just vectors $(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{15})$, no?

Comment: That is exactly my plan. :) But I'm not sure if I should use karatsuba or something else. I'll treat $GF(p^{16})$ elements as polynomials over $GF(p)$. All coefficients are itself sums to the base $2^{32}$. So I thought to use karatsuba @n=16 and again (16 times) @n=11.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I tried to implement the "Schoolbook Method", but it fails. Could you take a look on the internal logic, on which part this could fail? I'm not able to see it, since >24h.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I chose the Schoolbook Method on GF(p) and Karazuba on GF(p^16) in 2 iteration steps with another schoolbook multiplicaitons. This multiplication does no longer fail. But I'm interested in the Montgomery multiplication, but I cannot find any source, that deals with  returning A*B mod p. Do you know any?